# Subversion: how to make a working-directory on debian-webserver using windows repositories?

Tags: linux, windows, svn, tortoisesvn, debian

we have created our repositories on Windows-PC using tortoiseSVN. Now we would like to have on our webserver (Linux-Debian, directory ..../html/, reachable using our domain, user= www-data) a svn-working-copy.

Which steps are to be taken to create a svn-working-directory on our Debian-webserver from our Windows-repository?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running an actual Subversion server (Apache or svnserve), not simply accessing a repository created on a file share via file:///. Once you have that set up, just perform an `svn checkout` just like you would any other working copy.